# Android Permission gets Disabled by Default on Android 6+

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-permissions

I have many permissions in my app in Android, but when I install application of my device which is Android 7.1.2 I see not permission to Allow or Deny and when and the app starts running.

But when I go to Application Settings and check there for permission all permissions are denied.

If all permissions are denied my app is not going to work properly.
Can any one help me please.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Answer (score 0):

i dont have any perfect answer but just use target skd version less than 23. That might solve the issue. In the latest sdk one needs to set user permissions for every task they perform

Comment: Already published build with Target SDK 24, not cant down grade it its not allowed.